# Word wrap position in UILabel

Tags: uilabel, word-wrap

When working with a muti-line UILabel object, is there a way to know at which position in the text the line wrapping will occur?
For example if the text of my label is 20 words, the display will be different according to the size of the box provided. I would like to know when (character position) the display is going to the next line.